# How to remove "#" links from a list of links

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

I am using JSoup to list all links on a webpage, but after I ran my first program, I immediately noticed all the empty links or self links (`href="#"`). So I tried to remove these with following code:

```
if (link != "" && link != "#" && link != "/") {
    links.add(link);
}
```

However for some reason it only filters away the `""` and `"/"` links. I was thinking this has something to do with invisible characters, but I can't really figure it out. In my console all that show up as the link is `#`.

Is there anyone who knows whats going on?

Comment: Use String.equals to compare Strings

Comment: Of course! Totally forgot that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've compared the string the wrong way,

Here is the fix:

```
if ("".equals(link) && "#".equals(link) && "/".equals(link)) {
links.add(link);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out all links that starts with # or are empty or contains only / during the select query e.g.

```
document.select("a:not([href^=#])").select("a[href~=^/?[^/]+]");
```

This translates to **select all a tags elements that are not starting with # and may start with / but in this case they cannot contain only /**

Here you can find a sample Groovy script I prepared for test - https://gist.github.com/wololock/719985e6c48f40f8935f Java code is almost the same, just remember about ; at the end of each line and change ' to ". This example shows how to extract all links without any further filtration.